# How can I prevent Word from caching JS API Code?

Tags: javascript, html, ms-word, office-js, word-addins

I am developing a Microsoft Word Add-in in Office JS API. The add-in allows a document author or editor to select regions of text and create tags that associate the regions with index entries. The tags are hidden Ooxml strings. A second step iterates through the document body (also footnotes) and generates an index (with page number placeholders) at the end of the document. The final step is implemented in VSTO (C#), which again goes through the document and resolves the page number placeholders with actual page numbers (since JS API doesn't have access to them).

FWIW I'm using Word 2016 (Version 1908, Build 11929.20114 Click-to-Run) -- our organization uses Office 365, and the Word JS API 1.1 requirement set. The html, js and css code is hosted on a webserver -- there is a manifest xml file in a directory on the user's C: drive which points back to the webserver URL and that C: directory location is added to the Word>Options>Trust Center>Trust Center Settings> Trusted Add-in Catalogs list as `\\localhost\C$\directory name`. Then the add in is sideloaded from the Developer tab's Add-ins>Shared Folder list.
Clarification: this is what the manifest.xml file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:type="TaskPaneApp">
           <Id>e69eaa23-19f3-48fd-9f8e-694eb013e434</Id>
    <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
    <ProviderName>Microsoft</ProviderName>
    <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
    <DisplayName DefaultValue="PSU Indexing V2" />
    <Description DefaultValue="Manage and create document indexes." />
    <Hosts>
        <Host Name="Document"/>
    </Hosts>
    <DefaultSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://psuindexer.la.psu.edu/PSUIndexerV2/home.html" />
    </DefaultSettings>
    <Permissions>ReadWriteDocument</Permissions>
</OfficeApp>
```

One problem I'm having is that Word caches a very old version of the JS API code. I have gone into Internet Explorer (version 11.592.18362.0) and changed the Internet Options>General>Browsing History>Settings> and specified "Check for newer versions of stored pages: Every time I visit the webpage". On the advice at https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/632, I added meta http-equiv tags to the HTML as follows:

`<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />`

But the behavior is weirder than that. I can install the add in, modify the html and javascript on the website, and click the Reload button in the add-in and the pages are refreshed and the code is updated. But if I close the document and re-open it, it seems to have a cached version of very old code (ie. from yesterday). Reload doesn't fix the problem -- the only thing I can do is:
1) Close the add-in
2) Remove the location from trusted add-in catalogs
3) Close Word and reopen it
4) Add the location back into trusted add-in catalogs again
5) Close Word and reopen it again
6) Add the add in back from Developer>Add-ins>Shared Folder

Then it will work with the latest code  again just fine, until I close the word document, at which point upon reopening it it has yesterday's version again.

Can anyone explain what's going on here, or how I can fix it? The current situation would be unacceptable to me if I were an end-user.

Comment: Have you tried clearing the Office cache? See [Clear the Office cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/clear-cache).

Comment: Thanks, but no, that has no effect.

Comment: As a troubleshooting step, not a solution, try closing the add-in and Word; but leave the add-in catalog config alone. Then reboot the computer. Relaunch Word and the add-in. Do you get the latest version of the add-in or an old version?

Comment: I'm a little unclear about where you're serving your files. You say "webserver", but does this mean a server running on a different computer, or is the domain `localhost:xxxx`?

Comment: The path in the Trusted Catalogs should not be an HTML path with "localhost" in it. It should be a Windows networking path of the form "\\{MyComputer}\{MySharedManifestFolder}". For example, mine is "\\RickLaptop\AddinManifests". Notice that there is no string "localhost" and no "C:" although the AddinManifests folder is in the root of the C drive.

Comment: Thank you Rick regarding the Trusted catalogs path. I've edited my original question since there were typos in it. It was never an HTML path and there should have been a dollar sign instead of a colon after the "C".

Comment: also edited to include the manifest.xml file -- I hope that explains what I meant by "...which points back to the webserver URL"

Comment: I tried your troubleshooting step but I still get the old version after saving, closing and reopening the word document. The behavior has changed a little bit because I completed removed all trusted catalog locations except for a new one, where I mimicked what you'd done. It's now \\L2ITLA-WT0700\PSUIndexerV2test, which is a shared folder. But when I reload word, it tells me "ADD-IN ERROR Tis add-in is no longer available from the following server: localhost" This despite the fact that localhost is no longer mentioned.

Comment: Is that the complete manifest? If not, are there any other URLs in the manifest? If so, verify that they are all using the exact same domain.

Comment: Your 6 step de-trust/re-trust process has stirred old memories. I recall doing that when I first learned the platform about 4 years ago. I *think* the "solution" is to do all your dev/debug/testing on `localhost:xxxx`. Don't stage to a remote server until you know you won't be making any more file changes. If you follow that rule, then you only have to do the 6 step dance when you actually deploy a new version of the add-in. I'll ask around Microsoft and see if there's an alternate solution and more about this caching (actually seems to be *persisting* since rebooting doesn't fix it).

Comment: That is the complete manifest. What has been working for me, while the codebase is undergoing daily changes, is 1) deleting any ooxml tags and other changes in my document, 2) creating a new document, 3) copying/pasting document contents from the original to the new one. My concern is that there be a reliable way to instruct the ultimate end users to install the program and to be able to update it easily if there is a change. I feel that the caching that Word is doing needs to be more transparent -- there shouldn't need to be a 6 step dance. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Just a quick question -- if the code is changing should the version # in the manifest be changing too? Would that nudge Word not to cache?

Comment: You can try raising the version number, but I don't think it would help. I've been asked to ask you what server you are using?

Comment: About this "What has been working for me, while the codebase is undergoing daily changes, is 1) deleting any ooxml tags and other changes in my document, 2) creating a new document, 3) copying/pasting document contents from the original to the new one." Do you mean this has been working for you in the sense that it fixes the strange caching?

Comment: Yes, to test my code changes I need a fresh Word document, which fixes the caching -- so the caching is document-specific. it makes me think there is some way the add-in or my code has corrupted the original -- but at least I can get the document text.

Comment: Which server? Do you mean the server hosting https psuindexer.la.psu.edu? That is IIS 10 running on Windows Server 2016 Standard

Answer (score 0):

This is getting too complicated to handle comments, so I'll use an answer and delete this later.
Since it seems to be document-specific, let's try a couple of things:

1. Reproduce the caching, so you've got a doc open that is using a version of the add-in that you know is older than the the current version. Save that file under a different name. Then reopen the file and the add-in. Is it using the old or new version?
2. As in #1, save a copy of the file that is using the old version. Then go through your 3 step clean-up process so you've got a new document that's using the latest version. Save a copy of that. Add `.zip` to the end of both file names. (docx files are zip format.) Unzip them both. Then use a "diff"ing tool and see if there are any difference that might explain the caching.

Comment: 1) Item 1: The saved/renamed copy still has the error message. Interestingly, just opening it causes it to attempt to load the old add-in, and then when I want to close it it asks me if I want to save or not. If I do save, the next time I try to open it and close it without doing anything, it again asks me if I want to save it.

Comment: Item 2: The diffs are in two files: \DocProps\app.xml: Before the 3-step cleanup  tag is <Pages>1</Pages>  but in the cleaned file, it's <Pages>37</Pages>. FWIW, the doc is 37 pages long. 
Other diffs are in \word\settings.xml as follows:
uncleaned:
<w:rsid w:val="0077163C"/><w:rsid w:val="00772D26"/>
cleaned:
<w:rsid w:val="0077163C"/><w:rsid w:val="00772C25"/><w:rsid w:val="00772D26"/> 
uncleaned:
<w:rsid w:val="00BB176E"/><w:rsid w:val="00BB5DFA"/>
cleaned:
<w:rsid w:val="00BB176E"/><w:rsid w:val="00BB554F"/><w:rsid w:val="00BB5DFA"/>
I have no idea what this means!

Comment: Regarding #1, I don't think you mentioned an error message before. What is it and when/where do you see it?

Comment: The error message is the one I mentioned above in one of the comments: "ADD-IN ERROR This add-in is no longer available from the following server: localhost". I see it as soon as I open the document and it attempts to sideload the add-in -- I see it where the add-in should appear.

Comment: My bad. I searched for "error" on the page but I think ksome of the comments were collapsed when I searched.

Comment: The `rsid`s are save IDs. Every time the document is saved a new one is generated. It looks like your uncleaned has two pairs of saves. The cleaned has the same two saves (indicating that they happened before the split. But the cleaned file has two additional saves that seem to come in between the pairs, which seems weird.

Comment: Do you have admin access to the IIS server or know someone who does? If so, can you save an uncleaned file, shut down web app, then relaunch it, then reopen the doc and see if get the latest or an old version of the files?

Comment: Sorry, I was out sick for a couple of days. I tried this (stopping/restarting site in IIS) but it made no difference.

Comment: Just to be clear, when you reopened the file after restarting IIS, you got an old version of the add-in?

Comment: Yes. Here are a few other thoughts, which I'd be curious if you think are significant. 1) I notice that when I change the trusted catalog locations in the trust center, the word doc does not prompt me to save. That makes me think that wherever that setting is stored, it is not in the document. 2) I probably should have mentioned this before but it slipped my mind: the document in question was originally created on someone else's computer and emailed to me.

Comment: Re #1: Yes. That setting transcends any document and even the Office app. It applies across your entire Office suite installation. If you opened the trusted catalog setting in Excel or PowerPoint, you'd see the same setting as for Word. Re #2: I don't think that would have an effect.